# How to view logger info in flask when running in docker

Tags: docker, flask

I have to run a flask application in docker on Centos7. Now I have met some issues but I can only run flask application in docker wherever on local or on AWS. So where can I find the logger info?

There is my config.py:

```
import os
base_path = "/opt/cv_parser_data"

port = os.getenv('PORT', 3000)

store_dir_prefix = "%s/cv_store/" % base_path

log_path = "%s/log/" % base_path

tmp_file_path = "%s/tmp_file/" % base_path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this command:

`docker logs flask_container_id` or `docker logs -f flask_container_id`

Hope this help !

Comment: Thanks, but I can only get (115.193.26.79 - - [01/Aug/2019 03:07:55] "POST /?utm_src=1 HTTP/1.1" 200)

Comment: `docker logs flask_container_i | less` to show at the first to the end.

Comment: how was it going ?

Answer (score 0):

If without docker, you log was not print to stdout, then with docker, they will also not be print to stdout, then you could not see it with `docker logs`.

If above is your case, you had to enter into the container to see the log, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

For your case, you mentioned `log_path = "%s/log/" % base_path`, you many enter into container with next, then `cd` to above folder to check your logs.

```
docker exec -it $your_container_name /bin/bash
```